# In C#, is there a generic way to pass a DBSet to a method?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6, refactoring, dbset

I currently have the following working code:

```
        private Converter RemoveAll<T>(List<T> databaseSet) {
             databaseSet
                .ForEach(item =>  this.myContext.Remove(item));
            return this;
        }
```

which I can invoke like:

```
this.RemoveAll(this.myContext.Widgets.ToList());
this.RemoveAll(this.myContext.WhositsWhatsits.ToList());
// etc.
```

Where `this.myContext` is an instance of `MyContext` which extends `DbContext`; and `Widgets`, `WhositsWhatsits`, etc. are all instances of `DbSet`.

Because I always need to change the `DbSet` to a `List`, I'd rather just pass the `DbSet` as a parameter, like:

```
this.RemoveAll(this.myContext.Widgets);
this.RemoveAll(this.myContext.WhositsWhatsits);
// etc.
```

But if I change the method to:

```
        private Converter RemoveAll<T>(DbSet<T> databaseSet) {
             databaseSet.ToList()
                .ForEach(item =>  this.myContext.Remove(item));
            return this;
        }
```

The compiler complains "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbSet'.

Is it possible to modify this method so I can remove the need to invoke ToList() before calling it?

Comment: You can add the constraint ```where T : class```.

Comment: `where T : class`? However, you might look at repository pattern, pass `DbContext` to it and encapsulate all CRUD operations

Comment: are you looking for the [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method which can access different tables and be specified by a generic parameter. This way you don't even need to pass the dbset as parameter. Only specify it in the generic section

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski except... Entity Framework DbContext is *already* an implementation of the repository pattern. Wrapping it again *can* be an antipattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DbSet is restricted to have reference types as generic parameters. Therefore, you need to restrict your method to also work only for reference types. It can be acheved by using `where` clause as below.

```
private Converter RemoveAll<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> databaseSet) where TEntity : class
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using remove method, use removerange where you can avoid Call to ToList(). I have provided an extension method that will reduce code even more.

```
public static class DbContextExtension
{
    public static void RemoveAll<Tinput>(this DbSet<Tinput> dbset) where Tinput : class
    {
        dbset.RemoveRange(dbset);
    }
}
```

usage will be like.

```
 this.myContext.Widgets.RemoveAll();
```

if u dont need extension method, just use

dbset.RemoveRange(dbset);